# Removing am element when coming from a certain url

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, url-routing

this is my first question here, so I'm sorry if its asked in a dumb way…

I have a project where I used video intros on some pages.
In some certain cases I would like to skip those videos for example when the user goes back or comes from a certain other url.
My idea was to remove the  element with javascript.
Now the question: how do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain this further, "user goes back or comes from a certain other url". Your requirement is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.referrer` and conditionally show/hide your video based on the referrer URL. `document.referrer` will refer to the URL of the previous page.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //if you want control over full url
    if(document.referrer == "http://stackoverflow.com/") {
        $("#video").hide(); // Assuming #video is your video container
    }

    //if you want control over some part of url...
    if(document.referrer.indexOf("stackoverflow") > -1) {
        $("#video").hide(); // Assuming #video is your video container
    }
});
```

Comment: just a small change might work `document.referrer == "some URL"` couldn't be `document.referrer.contains("some URL")` for more control on urls text..

Comment: That depends if an exact match is needed or not -- which only OP knows. And JS does not contain a native `contains` method on `string` types.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do following :

1. Catch the parameter from URL
2. Use `if` condition to check parameter value
3. If `true` then hide or show

Comment: what if url does not have `parameters` ?

Comment: Then how will you differentiate, you need to have something in place to identify user?

Comment: sir, you can check @Saravana Sir answer

Comment: I think this is actually a better solution, asuming that you have access to the referrer website's HTML. You can add parameters to the URL, something like `site.com?showVideo=false`.

Comment: muhammad, that's what @Saravana answered. (With code)